# Animated crossfade table cells/rows?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm wondering if there is a way to fade out rows or cells of a table while also fading in replacement content, without creating nearly-duplicate tables, or tables within tables, etc.

This is an example of the type of table change I'm trying to do:

```js
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', function () {
 this.querySelector('#row1').classList.toggle('hidden')
 this.querySelector('#row2').classList.toggle('hidden')
})
```

```css
.hidden {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tr id="row1">
 <td colspan="4">Swap row</td>
</tr>
<tr id="row2" class="hidden">
 <td>Hi</td>
 <td colspan="3">there</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>This</td><td>is</td><td>an</td><td>example</td></tr>
<tr><td>example</td><td>an</td><td>is</td><td>This</td></tr>
</table>

Click the table.
```

Before you say anything, I am aware that the `display` property can't be animated. This code snippet is less about my attempt at implementation (because I don't know where to start) and more about the kind of content I'm looking to manipulate.

The closest (visually) I've been able to manage is something like this:

```js
document.querySelector('#table2').addEventListener('click', function () {
 this.classList.toggle('hidden')
 document.querySelector('#table3').classList.toggle('hidden')
})
document.querySelector('#table3').addEventListener('click', function () {
 document.querySelector('#table2').classList.toggle('hidden')
 this.classList.toggle('hidden')
})
```

```css
.hidden {
 transition: 1s;
 opacity: 0;
}

#table2, #table3 {
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<table id="table2" border="1">
<tr>
 <td colspan="4">Swap row</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>This</td><td>is</td><td>an</td><td>example</td></tr>
<tr><td>example</td><td>an</td><td>is</td><td>This</td></tr>
</table>
<table id="table3" border="1" class="hidden">
<tr>
 <td>Hi</td>
 <td colspan="3">there</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>This</td><td>is</td><td>an</td><td>example</td></tr>
<tr><td>example</td><td>an</td><td>is</td><td>This</td></tr>
</table>
```

But that's obviously not very good for a variety of reasons (absolute positioning messing up page flow, redundant content, assigning multiple event listeners, content layout rearranging, etc).

Comment: Related question [CSS transition with tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44290429/css-transition-with-tables)

Comment: You need this to be a TABLE element? because you can't overlap content on table cells, but you can overlap content on CSS grids and it also have the concept of columns, rows and cells.

Comment: I may not need to be a table, but I was trying to see if it was possible. I'm working on a calendar application ([ex](https://jsfiddle.net/therks/gu1bjfsn/)) and a table was the obvious route to go. I've never used CSS grids and am unfamiliar them. I will give them a look-see though.

Answer (score 0):

Fade animation not work in table.
Your have used div from create table.
For example

```
<div class=table>
  <div class=row>
    <div class=col></div>
    <div class=col></div>
  </div>
</div>

$('.col').click(function() {this.fadeOut(); }) ;
```